# 503 Service Unavailable Error in Magento Admin

Tags: admin, magento-2.1.4

I am getting "503 Service Unavailable" error only in magento admin. The error is displayed on admin user login, when navigating to any of the pages and while saving the configs. 
The error is intermittent and upon refreshing the page the error goes away and the page is loaded and displayed.

The site is not in maintenance mode and  I don't see maintenance.flag in root or var folder.

Any ideas/solutions to get rid of this problem ??

Comment: I am assuming since you mention `maintenance.flag` that you have run `php bin/magento maintenance:disable` is it?

Comment: Yes, maintenance mode is disabled and the status is not active.

Comment: What is your last changes in code?

Comment: We haven't made any changes in code recently. But still we get this error in backend.